# Creating an array for var

Tags: javascript

This should close any divs listed in the array when you click anywhere out side those divs, but it isn't working.

If I was to click anywhere that was not div1, div2, div3, div4 then all those divs should close.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $["#div1," "#div2", "#div3", "#div4"];

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

I can make it work for individual divs in their own script tags, but then I must reproduce this code several times, which isn't very neat.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#div1");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#div2");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#div3");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#div4");

    if (!container.is(e.target) 
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

What is the correct solution for grouping these #divs?

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong - use round brackets and put all comma separated ids between the quotes like this:

```
var container = $("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4");
```

Then all functions concerning `container` variable will affect all those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
  var container = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3", "#div4"];
  for(var i=0;i<container.length;i++)
 {
    if (!$(container[i]).is(e.target) 
    && $(container[i]).has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
    $(container[i]).hide();
    }
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way.

JS:

```
$(document).not($("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4")).on('click',function(){

   $(".test").hide();

})
```

HTML :

```
<div id="div1" class="test" style="background-color:red">111</div>
<div id="div2" class="test" style="background-color:blue">22</div>
<div id="div3" class="test" style="background-color:green">333</div>
<div id="div4" class="test" style="background-color:black">444</div>

<div id="div5" style="background-color:black">44455555555</div>
```